# Impossible to geolocalize with 3G

Tags: android, geolocation, google-api

In my application I need to geolocalize the mobile to calculate distance between 2 points.
So to do it i'm using Google API because result are better.

When i'm launching my app with WiFi everythings is OK, but when i'm using 3G the Json file of google says "Overlimit"

I'm using the free API access, and I haven't try other access to the API for the day.
Have you ever works with these API ?
Do you know where the problem is ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using 3G, the **external IP address** seen by Google Servers is being shared by a lot of 3G subscibers. Your network operator could be serving many clients from the same external IP, of whom a lot might have used the **Geolocation API**.

And the API limit is based on accesses from each IP address. Hence the issue. I'm afraid the only way to fix this is to [**get a license.**](https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing)

Comment: Thanks !
I was thinking that it was something like that, but now it's clear ;)